# Is there a way to use OnMouseOver to select a radgrid row?

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, radgrid

I am currently highlighting a row in a radgrid using OnMouseOver. I would like to know if it is possible to use OnMouseOver to select the row rather than highlight it.

Alternatively, I would like the highlighted row to remain highlighted if the radgrid loses focus, such as when a confirmation box pops up.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Telerik documentation, it should be possible to select the item OnMouseOver using the following code (if you don't have any detail tables you can nix the `if` statement and just use the code from the `else` block to find the `currentDataItem`):

```
function RadGrid1_RowMouseOver(sender, eventArgs) {
    var currentDataItem = null;

    // clear all currently selected items before selecting new
    sender.get_masterTableView().clearSelectedItems();

    if (eventArgs.get_itemIndexHierarchical().indexOf(':') > 0)
    {
        var detailTableIndex = eventArgs.get_itemIndexHierarchical().split(':')[0];
        var rowIndex = eventArgs.get_itemIndexHierarchical().split(':')[1].split('_')[1];
        currentDataItem = sender.get_detailTables()[detailTableIndex].get_dataItems()[rowIndex];
    }
    else
    {
        currentDataItem = sender.get_masterTableView().get_dataItems()[eventArgs.get_itemIndexHierarchical()];
    }

    if (currentDataItem != null)
    {
        currentDataItem.set_selected(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The other answers here do not work with the WPF Telerik RadGridView as we don't have access to RowMouseOver event.

For a WPF Telerik RadGridView, the best approach if the grid doesn't contain UI elements is to use ChildrenOfType<> in a Linq expression with IsMouseOver.

```
private void myGridView_MouseMove(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e)
{
    MyCustomClass myClass = null;

    var rows = this.myGridView.ChildrenOfType<GridViewRow>().Where(r => r.IsMouseOver == true);
    foreach (var row in rows)
    {
        if (row is GridViewNewRow) break;
        GridViewRow gvr = (GridViewRow)row;
        myClass = (MyCustomClass)gvr.Item;
    } 
    // do something with myClass here if we have found a row under mouse
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! Your solution worked great, but rows would not become unselected when mousing over another row even if AllowMultiRowSelection was set to False. The following code will select a single row in the radgrid when the mouse hovers over the row:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function grdUsers_RowMouseOver(sender, eventArgs) {

        var NumberItems = sender.get_masterTableView().get_dataItems().length;
        for (var count = 0; count < NumberItems; count++) {
            var currentDataItem = sender.get_masterTableView().get_dataItems()[count];
            if (count == eventArgs.get_itemIndexHierarchical()) {
                currentDataItem.set_selected(true);
            }
            else {
                currentDataItem.set_selected(false);
            }
        }
    } 
</script>
```

I called the function at the following location:

```
<ClientSettings AllowColumnsReorder="True" ReorderColumnsOnClient="True">
                    <Selecting AllowRowSelect="True" />
                    <ClientEvents OnRowMouseOver="grdUsers_RowMouseOver" />
                </ClientSettings>
```

Comment: I added the functionality you were looking for to the example above. I used clearSelectedItems() instead of looping through all of the items in the grid. Should have better performance when the grid contains many rows. Also, I'm not sure what the bigger picture is here, but are you sure you want to select the row on mouseover? If the user is not careful they might select the a different row they did not want to select when trying to move their mouse off the grid.

Comment: Much obliged! Selecting the row in my case has no functionality other than to highlight the row. The problem I was facing was that the row would not remain highlighted (unless the row was selected) when the user clicked the in row delete button and the confirmation box would pop up, causing the radgrid to lose focus. Now the user will have assurance they are deleting the correct row when confirming delete.